# Expanding macros in macros

Tags: clojure, macros

I have the following macro :

```
(defmacro add-children [this children]
  (map (fn [child] (list '.addChild this child)) children))
```

and I would like to create the following macro :

```
(defmacro defgom [name & body]
 (let [sym (gensym)]
  `(let [~sym (Model.)]
     (add-children sym body)))))
```

Considering that Model is a Java class with an `addChild` function. I would like to expand `defgom` to

```
(let [*gensym* (Model.)]
  (.addChild *gensym* (first body))
  (.addChild *gensym* (second body))
  ...
  (.addChild *gensym* (last body)))
```

When evaluated, the `add-children` macro gives the correct result (the list of `.addChild`). But I can't evaluate it in the `defgom` macro. I get a "Don't know how to create ISeq from: clojure.lang.Symbol". I tried with `~` or `~@` (given that `add-children` returns a list), but none worked.

How to properly expand the macro inside the macro?

PS: I know I can do it with a function rather than the `add-children` macro, but I want to know if it's possible to do it with a macro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change the last line to:

```
(add-children ~sym ~@body)
```